# How can I run one app from another app in iphone?

Tags: iphone

On some app , I see when one link touched , use safari for open link and quit from current app.
I want use from this feature for run messages app from other app. Can I do this? If yes, how can?

Comment: This might be useful http://handleopenurl.com/ . Example: http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/itunes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use -[UIApplication openURL:]. For example, you can use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.stackoverflow.com"]]
```

Note this will also switch to the new app. An application can register the URL schemes it supports using its plist.

Comment: Voted for this over the other as you mentioned how to register your own URL schemes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to start external application is to use [`UIApplication openUrl`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW14). The documentation says

> An object representing a URL
>   (Universal Resource Locator). UIKit
>   supports the http:, https:, tel:, and
>   mailto: schemes.

If you meant e-mail application, you can pass link according to [mailto:](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html) scheme. The simplest example is `@"mailto:someone@example.com"`.

Comment: I want open Message application ! there are any way?

Answer (score 0):

I do it , I write sms in mailto place and write phone number in front of it.
and app work correct,

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"sms:09120000000"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you need use URL Schemes:

Essentially, one app registers the fact that it handles a particular URL prefix, and then to launch that app, you have to navigate to that URL.

You can pass parameters through this URL too

If you meant e-mail application, you can pass link according to mailto: scheme. The simplest example is @"mailto:someone@example.com".

Thanks :)