# Including an iOS app into another app

Tags: ios

I have two apps AppA and AppB . I need to merge it into one . i.e when I tap on a button in AppA it should go to AppB. Both app has so many classes with same name. Is this possible?

Help me if you have any idea.

Comment: Vishnu please view my edited answer...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** :

Well I could help you somehow.... What you can do is open one appn from the other. That is open AppB from AppA. You would need the URL Schema of AppB in that case. So check out these links

[How can I run one app from another app in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666580/how-can-i-run-one-app-from-another-app-in-iphone)

[Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

[How Can I open another App from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051271/how-can-i-open-another-app-from-my-app)

Please have a look at the following links also. Your issue maybe similar to them:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582544/ios-combine-multiple-app-in-one-app

[Merging multiple iOS apps with a menu system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674514/merging-multiple-ios-apps-with-a-menu-system)

Hope this helps.